# Limit Python Web Scrape to Specific Text?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Apologies if this is silly, the first time I opened Python was around four hours ago.

I've been hobbling a basic script together to scrape the URLs from a specific web page.

At the moment, it's pulling in all of the URLs - i.e.:

> /review/domainiwanttokeep.com
>
> /review/domainiwanttokeep2.com
>
> /review/domainiwanttokeep3.com
>
> https:/domainimscraping.com/jobs
>
> https:/domainimscraping.com/blog
>
> https:/domainimscraping.com/contact

This in general is fine, but what I would really like to do is have the scrape only display the /review/domainiwanttokeep.com domains to help cleanse the list and automatically remove the URLs I don't need.

I assume there must be something I can do with /review/ as a keyword to ensure it only displays the text after each of these?

The script in its current format is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://extracteddomain-unsureifitbreaksrules.com")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be massively appreciated!

I've tried to filter out the links using if, but seem to be creating the script incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`css selector`](https://%20https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for example, that selects all `<a>` with `href` starting with `/review/`:

```
soup.select('a[href^="/review/"]')
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<a href="/review/domainiwanttokeep.com">my link</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[
    a.get('href')
    for a in soup.select('a[href^="/review/"]')
]
```